# Idiomatic way to initialise std::optional from another std::optional and something else

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17, idioms

I want to initialise an `std::optional` from another `std::optional` and some additional arguments provided that the latter `std::optional` is not empty. Unfortunately [`std::optional::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) 4) and 5) are not suitable as the amount of arguments is different.

I was able to come up with the following, but it still feels excessive. I particularly don't like specifying return type for the lambda explicitly.

Is there an better (as in more succinct and more expressive) way to achieve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <tuple>

struct A {
    A(std::optional<int> oi, float f, char c)
    :
        val{
            [&] () -> decltype(val) /* I don't like specifying type here */ {
                if (oi)
                    return {{*oi, f, c}};
                else
                    return std::nullopt;            
            }()
        }
    {
    }

    std::optional<std::tuple<int, float, char>> val;
};

int main()
{
    auto print = [](auto& r) {
        if (r)
            std::cout
                << std::get<0>(*r) << "; "
                << std::get<1>(*r) << "; "
                << std::get<2>(*r) << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "nullopt" << std::endl;
    };

    auto one = A({}, 1.0, 'c');
    print(one.val);

    auto two = A(10, 2.0, 'c');
    print(two.val);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1754506892fc0c47).

Comment: `val{ oi ? decltype(val){{*oi, f, c}} : std::nullopt }`?

Comment: @zneak yep, it will work, but can we get rid of `decltype` by any chance?

Comment: Typedef it? I think that your hands are tied by how type inference works here.

Comment: The "real idiomatic" way to deal with this would be to have a `flat_map` function to go with `std::optional`, but I don't think that there's a standard one.

Comment: `std::tuple{*oi, f, c}` is probably clearer than the `decltype`, though they're not identical.

Comment: @chris will this work with ternary operator? `std::tuple` and `std::nullopt` are different types. `decltype`, OTOH, will include `std::optional`.

Comment: Good point there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just trust the compiler to do the right thing:

```
A(std::optional<int> oi, float f, char c) {
    if (oi) {
        val.emplace(*oi, f, c);
    }
}
```

This is also of course a great use-case for a `map()` member function<sup>†</sup>, which you can write as a non-member function:

```
A(std::optional<int> oi, float f, char c)
    : val(map(oi, [&](int i){ return std::tuple(i, f, c); }))
{ }
```

---

<sup>†</sup>Recently proposed in [P0798](https://wg21.link/p0798) by TartanLlama.

Comment: So no chance to avoid default-construction of `val` in the first example before `map()` is in the standard?

Comment: @DevNull Is that bad? Default-constructing an optional is just setting a bool. The compiler will optimize it properly, my example and your example generate [identical code](https://godbolt.org/g/C1EsgX).

Comment: no, it's not "bad", I just hoped that there's some way to both leave it in the member initialiser list and avoid specifying type explicitly.

Comment: @DevNull The `map` solution above does exactly that?  (It is the `map` function from  Haskell, sometimes called `fmap`)

Comment: @Yakk yes, but it's not in the standard (maybe yet).

Comment: @drv write it, it is a free function